# Drupal user one off settings

Tags: drupal, grouping, registration

I am putting together a complex Drupal user driven website. One thing I need to accomplish early on is to put users into groups as they register.

**Can anyone tell me how I can get them to register particular details which they will not be able to amend in the future?** Such data as the users gender etc....?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module, which lets you use nodes with whatever custom CCK fields you need (for, say, Gender, etc.) as user profiles. And then through permissions you can choose whether or not users can edit their profiles by setting the usual permissions (create, edit, etc) for the node type Profile.